# Anaconda environment recover:How to recover an Anaconda environment that was deleted by mistake

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I have removed an pytorch environment in anaconda, which used in anaconda UI,how can i recover the pytorch environment. I live in china, the vpn speed is low, I donnot want to reinstall the env again. How can i do this?
thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The env file folder are exisited in the user/anaconda3/env, but cannot indexes it